Extract answers from users while in conversation
I am building a chatbot that allows users to ask questions based on a 500-word paragraph. However, I also have a set of 5 predefined questions for which I want to collect answers from the users. How can I achieve this?
I am using gemini models, for chatbot.
It would be a great help, if anyone can guide me.
